# Beautifulsoup: Can't find tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm a Python beginner and I started using beautifulsoup a few weeks ago. Right now I'm trying to build a simple project to scrape the country information of the reviews posted on some Aliexpress products. When I inspect the HTML code from the website, I see that what I should look for inside beautifulsoup is class="css_flag ..." (see attached picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgMae.png) but I can´t find it.

I have tried to extract all the 'b' tags and had no luck. I also printed the entire soup in the console, then copied it to a wordfile and did a manual search for  class="css_flag ..." and found nothing.

This is the code that I'm using right now

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


tags = soup('b')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag)
```

I expect the code to return all the strings that include "css_flag" in it. I would really appreciate some help with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: did you check actual `html` code you get? i.e. if they use javascript what you see in the browser may be different from the html you get (i.e. javascript content not rendered).

Comment: It's possible those elements or the class are created by Javascript so won't be available in the initially downloaded data. Try downloading the URL you're trying to open to a file and see what is present in a text editor.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Is there a way in which I can download that javascript information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another url you'll use to access that. You'll need to provide some query data, like the productId number, etc., but you can get what you're after. Code/example below:

```
import bs4
import requests

request_url = 'https://feedback.aliexpress.com/display/productEvaluation.htm'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'v': '2',
'productId': '33023202345',
'ownerMemberId': '232182005',
'companyId': '241422497',
'memberType': 'seller',
'startValidDate':'',
'i18n': 'true'}

res = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, params=payload)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
tags = soup('b')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag)
```

**Output:**

```
<b class="r-graph-scroller" style="width:94.0%;"></b>
<b class="r-graph-scroller" style="width:5.0%;"></b>
<b class="r-graph-scroller" style="width:0.0%;"></b>
<b class="r-graph-scroller" style="width:1.0%;"></b>
<b class="r-graph-scroller" style="width:0.0%;"></b>
<b>4.9</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
<b class="css_flag css_ru">RU</b>
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much for the help!!

Comment: I was wondering if you could please explain how this script works since I would really like to understand why this method works and the regular code that I posted didn't. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, I just sent you an email.